# How to convert German Letters from csv to uft8 in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a csv file which contains both English and German Words. But there are certain German Words like Umlaut which are not displaying rather it gives some error. I am trying to use Flutter charcoad library for special characters but issue is still there.

For example, to display Hören, I have replaced it with H\u00D6ren in csv. But now it shows exactly H\00D6ren rather then Hören.

**my CSV file:**

German Word,German Sentence,English Word,English Sentence

die Ansage,Hören Sie auf die Ansagen,announcement,Listen to the announcements

**Below is part of the code**(Original Code taken from GitHub and then updated)

```
import 'package:csv/csv.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart' show rootBundle;
import 'package:transformer_page_view/transformer_page_view.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
// This widget is the root of your application.
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return MaterialApp(
  title: 'Flutter-Flashcard',
  theme: ThemeData(
    primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
  ),
  home: MyHomePage(title: 'German Vocabulary'),
);
  }
  }

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

final String title;

@override
_MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
     @override
     Widget build(BuildContext context) {
     return FutureBuilder<String>(
    future: rootBundle.loadString('lib/assets/questions.csv'), //
    builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<String> snapshot) {
      List<List<dynamic>> csvTable =
      CsvToListConverter().convert(snapshot.data);

      print(csvTable);
      
      );
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

If you decode the words(utf8.decode) before retrieving it should work

Comment: Kindly can you confirm where exactly I have to decode the words. Final CSV will contain many such words. I used below line of codes but it did not work.

`var encoded = UTF8.encode("Îñţérñåţîöñåļîžåţîờñ");
var decoded = UTF8.decode([0x62, 0x6c, 0xc3, 0xa5, 0x62, 0xc3, 0xa6,
                           0x72, 0x67, 0x72, 0xc3, 0xb8, 0x64]);`

Answer (score 0):

csv was not in utf-8 though i save it as utf-8. You need to convert it to utf-8.

Excel to CSV with UTF8 encoding

The method which work for me was:

Open Google Sheet and

1-On the main Docs (or Drive) screen click the "Create" button and choose "Spreadsheet" 2-From the "File" menu choose "Import" 3-Click "Choose File" 4-Choose "Replace spreadsheet" 5-Choose whichever character you are using as a Separator 6-Click "Import" 7-From the "File" menu choose "Download as" -> CSV (current sheet)

The resulting file will be in UTF-8

Comment: Please format your code so that it could be readable.